# Error: TypeError: t.cssHooks is undefined useing jquery validation and datepicker

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery datepicker js and validation js but datepicker show but after select date not close datepicker window as calendar.

```
Error: TypeError: t.cssHooks is undefined useing  jquery validation and datepicker
Timestamp: 11/7/2013 7:01:46 PM
    Error: TypeError: t.cssHooks is undefined
    Source File: jquery-ui.min.js
```

Comment: the error is not enough. you need to provide either a fiddle or at least your html that is related to your question

Comment: where is the code????

Comment: as a starting point why don't you add information like browser used, jQuery & jQuery UI versions used etc... also as a debugging step use non minified versions of the library file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

May be the problem is occur due to using different version of jQuery and jQuery UI for validation and date-picker.

I have created a sample with jQuery validation and datepicker on [phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/3pv-g8r).

May be it will solve your problem.

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/3pv-g8r